# What is the probability that a Sum of 500 iid uniform variables that lie in [0,1] to be between 245 and 260?

Tags: statistics

I think a convolution of 500 uniform pdfs could be the way forward, however this sounds too complicated.

Is there a simpler way? a "trick" perhaps, that utilizes some special features of a sum of uniformly distributed iid numbers?

Comment: You can approximate using the central limit theorem, but an exact probability is hard to get.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of a large number of IID random variables (from any distribution with a finite mean and variance) is well-approximated by a normal distribution. The mean of the normal distribution is the sum of the means of the IID random variables, and the variance of the normal distribution is the sum of the variances of the IID random variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the *exact* answer, the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is what you want.

The sum of $500$ IID variables has a mean which is $500$ times the mean of each variable, and a standard deviation which is $\sqrt{500}$ times larger, and it will be very close to normally distributed.

A uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ has mean $0.5$ and standard deviation $\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}$. Thus what we want is a normal random variable with mean $250$ and standard deviation $\frac{\sqrt{500}}{2\sqrt3}\approx 6.45$. What is the probability that this variable lies between $245$ and $260$?